# Correct initialisation syntax with char in struct

Tags: struct, initialization

What is the correct syntax of a struct with char arrays ?
the nvsName gives me an error while compiling
And: is there another way to get initialize a value if the type is unknown ? Here I use the void*.

```
typedef struct
{
  char nvsName[];
  uint8_t type;
  void* p;
} NVS_CONFIG;

NVS_CONFIG nvs = {'123',0,(void*)VdmConfig.configFlash.netConfig.staticIp};
```

Answer (score 0):

your code contains multiple problems:

first : `'123'` is characther constant (see : [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Character_constants)) not a string as you would expect with `"123"` and characther constant is an int.

second : `nvsNames` shoud be a pointer or have a constant size otherwise your code will not compile.

```c
typedef struct
{
  char * nvsName;
  uint8_t type;
  void* p;
} NVS_CONFIG;

NVS_CONFIG nvs = {"123",0,(void*)VdmConfig.configFlash.netConfig.staticIp};
```

should at least fix the probems you currently have.